# Why does Ruby compiler count expected number of arguments in this case as zero?

Tags: ruby

I am quite new to the Ruby, and I ran into problem with defining an object of a class. If I understand correctly, def initialize should ask for three calues, but the code compiles with an error that three is given, but it expected zero values.

I thought the mistake there would be in attr_accessor, but a quick test showed that this is not a case.

The ruby version is 2.6.4

> test.rb:16:in `new': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

```
class Battler
  attr_accessor :health, :damage, :armor,
  def initialize(health, damage, armor)
    @health = health
    @damage = damage
    @armor = armor
  end

  def able?
    return @health > 0
  end

end

knight = Battler.new(1000, 10, 3)
goblin = Battler.new(20, 6, 1)
```

The problem starts with a

```
knight = Battler.new(1000, 10, 3)
```

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of `attr_accessor :health, :damage, :armor,` and all will be well.

Comment: My gosh, thanks! It worked!

Comment: It appears that the comma I asked you to remove is telling Ruby that the `attr_accessor` method has one or more arguments that continue on the following line. Why the definition of `initialize` doesn't raise an exception is a mystery to me. However, `Battler.instance_method(:initialize).owner #=> Battler; Battler.instance_method(:initialize).parameters #=> []` tells us that the method `initialize` was created with no arguments, which is consistent with your error message. Very odd.

Comment: The same result obtains if the first line were `attr_accessor :health, :damage, :armor, def initialize(health, damage, armor)`, followed by `@health = health`, and so on.

Comment: Why should it raise an exception? It may not make sense here but it's perfectly legal code. Otherwise 'fake keywords' like `private` (as in `private def foo`) wouldn't work.

Comment: The value of `def initialize; end` is `:initialize` so OP basically wrote `attr_accessor :initialize`.

Comment: @cremno, great observation! Please post as an answer, elaborating a bit as I'm not sure all readers will understand your point. (The correct method `:initialize` was created [with three arguments], but was then immediately overwritten by the accessor for `@initialize`.) As an aside, I can't understand why someone has voted to close this question. It's a great question!

Answer (score 4):

As you may know `attr_accessor` accepts a list of symbols (or strings) and for each one two methods are defined: a so-called a setter (e.g. `health=`) and getter (`health`). A list (not an actual type btw.) is one or several expressions separated by a comma, so in your case Ruby expected another expression after `:armor` because you put a comma thereafter.

(If the trailing comma was intentional, tell us. Some programmers use and recommend them in certain cases (and depending on the language). Though it would make any answer a bit more complicated since Ruby is actually fine with them - just not in this case.)

However that's only one part of your bug's explanation. One of Ruby's most basic features as a programming language is that nearly everything has a value (expressions). For example, try something like `x = if ...` in other languages! It often won't work as many languages have if-statements, not if-expressions.

In Ruby method definitions are also expressions: defining a method via `def` (`def foo; end`) used to return `nil`. Since Ruby 2.1 method definitions return the method's name (`:foo`). Now the return value of def-expressions may not seem to be very useful to you and it isn't in many cases but you probably agree the method name (`:foo`) is certainly more useful than `nil`.

The primary use case for this are methods like `private`, `public`, `method_function`, etc. which aren't keywords but are used like one (their defining feature is for calls the parentheses are omitted):

```
private def foo
end
# before 2.1
private  # from now on every method in this class context will be private
def foo
end
# or
def foo
end
private :foo  # only foo will be private but we have to repeat the name
```

Our friend `attr_accessor` is also such a keyword-like method but the value of `def` expressions is more important here. Remember it's the name of a method as a symbol. You wrote (simplified):

```
attr_accessor :health, :damage, :armor,
def initialize(health, damage, armor)
end

# which after the method was defined becomes
attr_accessor :health, :damage, :armor, :initialize
```

To make it a bit more clear - without `attr_accessor` your code might look like this:

```
class Battler
  def initialize(health, damage, armor)  # takes 3 required arguments
  end
  def health
    @health
  end
  def health=(v)
    @health = v
  end
  # damage, armor
  def initialize  # takes no arguments
    @initialize
  end
  def initialize=(v)
    @initialize = v
  end
end
```

You see you're redefining `Battler#initialize` and your new one doesn't take arguments because getters usually don't.

Redefinitions aren't treated as errors since they can be intentional however Ruby can emit a warning for you. Run `ruby -w test.rb` on the command line and it outputs:

> ```
> test.rb:15: warning: assigned but unused variable - knight
> test.rb:16: warning: assigned but unused variable - goblin
> test.rb:2: warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize
> test.rb:3: warning: previous definition of initialize was here
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>          1: from test.rb:15:in `<main>'
> test.rb:15:in `new': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
> ```

Here you can see that in line 2 the `initialize` method which was originally defined on line 3 is redefined. If you're confused why line 3 comes before line 2 here, then remember that the method definition is part of the list passed to `attr_accessor` so the def-expr has to be evaluated before the call.

Comment: Check: `:initialize=` is defined, not `:initialize`. Try call `Battler.new.methods`

Comment: I agree you should never ignore warnings, they are there for a reason!

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer! As for that extra comma, well, there should have been other variables, but I decided to check the code with not much of other code, just so the basic things work... And it seems I have missed one last comma when deleting them. So no magic or high-techy stuff here.