# Ruby identical user defined functions return differently

Tags: ruby, class, user-defined-functions

only one of these functions ('render' & 'render_all') prints to terminal while the other returns "nil". I can swap them around and even make them identical. One will always work and print while the other returns "nil". I can't figure out why. I need to display all faces of my tile class at end which requires render_all and i need to render it partially while game is still playing.

```
 class Board

  def initialize(size, bombs)
    @size = size 
    explosives = bombs
    @grid = Array.new(size) {Array.new(size) {Tile.new}}

    while explosives != 0
      potential_bomb = @grid[rand(0...size)][rand(0...size)]
      if potential_bomb.bomb == false
        potential_bomb.bomb = true
        potential_bomb.face = "X"
        explosives -= 1
      end
    end    
  end

  attr_accessor :size, :grid, 


   def render
    grid.each do |row|
      row.each do |box|
        if box.shown == true
          print "#{box.face}"
        else
          print "#"
        end        
      end
      print "\n"
    end
  end

  def render_all
    grid.each do |row|
      row.each do |box|
        print "#{box.face}"
      end
    end
  end

  def solved
    solved = true
    grid.each do |row|
        row.each {|pos| solved = false if pos.shown != true && pos.bomb == false}
    end
    return solved
  end

  def [](pos)
    x,y = pos
    grid[x][y]
  end
end
```

Comment: you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174877/why-does-ruby-compiler-count-expected-number-of-arguments-in-this-case-as-zero/ (not your fault for not finding it though) - always enable warnings!

Comment: FWIW, while it looks like a good dupe candidate (issue same, finding it, not so much), I hesitate to call what could *easily* be deliberate a "typo". I use trailing commas (not so much in Ruby, but sometimes) on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
attr_accessor :size, :grid,
```

See that trailing comma? Is bad.

FWIW: any time there's an issue that appears order-dependent always look immediately *above*; it's often unrelated to the order-dependent things, rather the result of screwing something up earlier.