# Instance Methods Class Error: in `new': wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, object

Hi I am just getting the following error: "in `new': wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 0) (ArgumentError)"

In *app/services/quarterback.rb* I have:

```
class Quarterback
attr_accessor :id, :firstname, :secondname, :club, :position, :price, :totalpoints,
def initialize(id, firstname, secondname, club, position, price, totalpoints)
    @id = id
    @firstname = firstname
    @secondname = secondname
    @club = club
    @position = position
    @price = price
    @totalpoints = totalpoints
end

def info
    "#{firstname} works for #{club} and has a cost of #{price}."
end

sparky = Quarterback.new('1', 'John', 'Edgar', 'Liverpool', 'Forward', '100', '38' )
puts sparky.info
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm voting to close this question as being caused by a typo. I don't want to discourage you from posting in the future if you find that this question gets closed; typos in code are a standard reason for closure because questions with them are unlikely to help others in the future.

Comment: Oh wow such a stupid mistake. Appreciate the response

Comment: I recommend using tools catch these kinds of errors. You can add [Ruby-LSP](https://github.com/Shopify/ruby-lsp) to your Gemfile and then enable it with a [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.ruby-lsp). You can also benefit from [the Ruby extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby), especially if you also install [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop). With these extensions I *can't* have a trailing comma; it immediately shows `Lint/TrailingCommaInAttributeDeclaration` and auto-corrects on save.

Comment: I would really recommend that you read up on keyword arguments - there ain't no way you or anyone else is ever going to be able to remember that method signature and if you miss a single positional argument you're screwed. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have a `,` at the end of line 2:

`attr_accessor :id, :firstname, :secondname, :club, :position, :price, :totalpoints,`

to be replaced with

`attr_accessor :id, :firstname, :secondname, :club, :position, :price, :totalpoints`

For a more detailed explanation as to why that error was triggered, I would suggest to have a read at this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176158/11330290

Comment: Sorry such a stupid mistake that I couldn't find. Thanks!